# Starting an activity before phonecall is placed

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm making an app where a BroadcastReceiver intercepts an outgoing call and starts an activity with an AlertDialog right before the phonecall is actually placed. I've tested on several phones with different results. On two of the phones I've tested everything works great, the activity is started before the call is placed and therefore "interupts" the phonecall. After the activity is shut down, the phonecall resumes as normal.

On the third phone, an HTC, this doesn't work. The phonecall is placed before the activity starts. How can I prevent this? Are there any priorities I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wide world of HTC headaches when it comes to android development, specifically regarding broadcast receivers. Sense always seems to handle things differently, or in some special way. Though this isn't really the best answer, it is too long for a comment. After looking around a bit, this is a known issue with HTC. A quick fix seemed to have been found at [Problem with interecepting outgoing calls on HTC Desire](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HiMjDPquUDg), though somewhat outdated.

They state that you can try

> As it seems the HTC Desire (2.2) responds to `setResultData(null)`
>   which will stop the out dial. Then you can place a new intent
>   (Action.CALL) to call the  new number. Not so nice workaround, but as
>   a user you hardly notice it.

Again I am not even sure if this works, or is the answer you are looking for, but it was too much for a comment :P

Comment: I appreciate your quick answer and your statement reveals my fear about HTC. The method you speak of should work so I might use that unless I find another method.

Comment: @Carl Bear Stefansson No worries, like I say I am not sure about this situation specifically, but I know that I beat my head against a wall for a while trying to figure out a workaround for HTC's quick boot not sending out a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and not receiving a QUICK_BOOT broadcast. Figure Sense is just really weird on that end.